# Fetch location when application is in killed state or background state (flutter)

Tags: flutter, geolocation, location, latitude-longitude

I want to fetch location when application is in killed state.
How to do it in flutter?

Comment: Witch background are you using? With Firebase send un cloud message and in the background fonction you can anwser to your data base.